# NHibernate update causes a select of a row's computed columns

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've got a User class that I want to update. There's a User table in my database with two columns among others: FirstName and Lastname and there's a computed column called DisplayName that concatenates the two with a space in the middle. The NHibernate mapping for DisplayName is

```
<property name="DisplayName" type="string" generated="always"/>
```

When I update the User object and commit the transaction, NHibernate runs an extra select statement just on the DisplayName property, I presume to keep the object and the DB row in sync. I don't need that as the object goes out of scope right afterwards.

Is there something I can do to tell NHibernate that there's no need to get the updated DisplayName at this time?

Regards,
F.

Comment: Can't answer that, but why not just make that computation part of the User object? (e.g. a c# property which concatenates the Firstname and Lastname properties). That way you don't have to involve the data access layer.

Comment: Is this in the mapping so that you can select/search against displayname?

Comment: @UpTheCreek - I was going to say the same thing but then I figured maybe he's trying to query against it. I've only ever done 'fullname' type things as a property in the class, never as part of the mapping.

Comment: Hi, I've been thinking about that but since the computation is already happening in the DB I thought I'd rather avoid doing it twice. Besides, if I want to bring back a list of Users, I'd rather do away with the overhead of the concatenation of 3 strings per row.

Comment: Why do it in the database, if you do it in code then you can change the format on a user-by-user basis. Some people perfer Lastname, Firstname, while others perfer FirstName LastName. Having it formatted in a property as aposed to pre-computed at the db allows for the flexibility.

Comment: That's an option but I've also got other columns such as Age which is calculated between the user's date of birth and the current date. I've also a generated code which takes the primary key as a component and suffixes it to an nvarchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generated="always"` means exactly that: "this is a value generated by the DB every time I modify this row; please refresh it for me".

NH does not have a concept like "only refresh this if a particular column changed".

My opinion is that you should generate that value in your domain model instead of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `generated="always"` with `insert="false" update="false"`. It will disable inserts and updates to this column and will not make an extra select statement to refresh the value.